# Custom directive (swipe) for ion content ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to add a directive(swipeVertical) to my ion nav but it seems that does not work, do you know if there are limitations for do that in ionic 2?

If I add the directive to the footer it works perfectly but it does not work for the

```
<ion-content scroll="false" (click)="handlePageClick($event)" >
    <ion-grid class="no-padding">
        <ion-row class="no-padding">
            <ion-col class="no-padding" col-2>
                <app-menu [menu]='menu'
                          (menuClicked)='navigationHandler($event)'>
                </app-menu>
            </ion-col>

            <ion-col class="main-view no-padding" col-10 >
                <ion-nav #mycontent [root]="rootPage" swipeVertical></ion-nav>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

        <app-footer ></app-footer>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution, I forgot to add the directive to the @NgModule exports